# Superscripting any Letter/Number

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, unicode, superscript

Is there actually any way to superscript any number? In my App I need to superscript the numbers from 0 to 24. 
 I know that with `\u2070` for example I can display a superscripted 0, but in Unicode there aren't all the numbers I need. 
 I just want to set a NSString to a number with an exponent, like 10^24. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Check out the Unicode tables here http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are scattered throughout the Unicode blocks:

- `\u2070` is superscript 0
- `\u00B9` is superscript 1
- `\u00B2` is superscript 2
- `\u00B3` is superscript 3
- `\u2074` is superscript 4
- `\u2075` is superscript 5
- `\u2076` is superscript 6
- `\u2077` is superscript 7
- `\u2078` is superscript 8
- `\u2079` is superscript 9

To put them altogether and make it easier to choose the digit, you can either use a `wchar_t[]` type, or store them in a string:

```
NSString *superDigits = @"\u2070\u00B9\u00B2\u00B3\u2074\u2075\u2076\u2077\u2078\u2079";
```

As an exercise you could create a method that formats an integer as a superscript string.

Comment: Note that in most typefaces in iOS, numbers 1,2 and 3 look different to the rest. See this question for more details (and a list of typefaces that are consistent):http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663251/why-the-display-of-unicode-characters-for-superscripted-digits-are-not-at-the-sa/7663610#7663610

Comment: +1 @jrturton: Yes, I've noticed this in a number of fonts too. I suppose the alternative was for TUC to define `\u2070 ~ \u2079` as superscript digits that have `\u00B2`, `\u00B3`, and `\u00B9` as duplicates... but multiple codepoints for the same glyph is probably more ugly than logically sequential characters with non-sequential codepoints.

Comment: @BharatDodeja: There is no contiguous series for superscript letters in Unicode, they all belong to different regions and as such they may have a different "look" than others. Check [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aUnicode_subscripts_and_superscripts#Superscripts_and_subscripts_block).

Comment: I tried the above super script code but code of 2 and 3 (\u00B2\u00B3\) is not working. Its displaying few special symbols on label. please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

Well, there **are** all the numbers you need. [Look here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aUnicode_subscripts_and_superscripts#Superscripts_and_subscripts_block)

Example:

```
ruby-1.9.3 > "1\u2070\u00B9\u00B2\u00B3\u2074\u2075\u2076\u2077\u2078\u2079"
 => "1⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹"
```