# Display special characters (utf-8) in wp7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, encoding, utf-8

So I'm using an api and I'm getting json back - problem is it's in German and when I try to display that string in a TextBox (after assigning it to a variable, of course). it is displayed incorrectly.
This is a sample of the result string I get back:

```
"{\"response_status\":\"success\",\"data\":{\"threads\":[{\"title\":\"30\\u00e2\\u0082\\u00ac Facebook Werbeanzeigen Guthaben Gratis\",\"deal_link\":\"http:\\/\\/hukd.mydealz.de\\/freebies\\/30-facebook-werbeanzeigen-guthaben-gratis\\/99359\",\"mobile_deal_link\":\"http:\\/\\/hukdm.mydealz.de\\/freebies\\/30-facebook-werbeanzeigen-guthaben-gratis\\/99359\",\"deal_image\":\"http:\\/\\/hukd.mydealz.de\\/images\\/threads\\/99359_1.jpg\",\"deal_image_highres\":\"http:\\/\\/hukd.mydealz.de\\/images\\/threads\\/high-res\\/99359_1.jpg\",\"description\":\"Ich habe letzens versucht bei Facebook eine Werbeanzeige zu schalten, habe aber dann im letzten Schritt bei Zahlungsform abgebrochen. Nun habe ich ein paar Tage sp\\u00c3\\u00a4ter eine E-Mail von Facebook mit einem 30\\u00e2\\u0082\\u00ac Gutschein bekommen:\\r\\n\\r\\n\\\"Wir haben festgestellt, dass Du in der Vergangenheit versucht hast, eine Facebook-Werbeanzeige zu erstellen. Wir bieten Dir jetzt einen Gutschein im Wert von 30 \\u00e2\\u0082\\u00ac an, damit Du Deine erste Werbeanzeige kostenlos erstellen kannst! (Dieses Angebot ist zeitlich begrenzt.)\\r\\n\\r\\nMit Facebook-Werbeanzeigen kannst Du:\\r\\n\\r\\nDein Zielpublikum mithilfe von geografischen Angaben, Alter und Interessen erreichen.\\r\\nKundenbeziehungen durch das Verlinken Deiner Facebook-Seite vertiefen.\\r\\nDein Tagesbudget festlegen und das Auftauchen \\u00c3\\u00bcberraschender Rechnungen vermeiden.\\r\\nKlicke hier um Deine kostenlose Werbeanzeige zu erstellen und den Gutscheincode einzul\\u00c3\\u00b6sen: xxxxxxx. Dein Gutschein verf\\u00c3\\u00a4llt am 02\\/08\\/2012. L\\u00c3\\u00b6se ihn also schon jetzt ein!\\r\\n\\r\\n\\r\\nIch sch\\u00c3\\u00a4tze mal das diese Gutscheine automatisch verschickt werden, wenn man eine Anzeigenerstellung abgebrochen hat.\",\"submit_time\":\"2 hours, 24 minutes ago\",\"hot_date\":false,\"poster_name\":\"Urlaubspiraten\",\"temperature\":50.1899986267,\"price\":0,\"timestamp\":1341323522,\"expired\":\"false\",\"forum\":{\"name\":\"Freebies\",\"url_name\":\"freebies\"},\"category\":{\"name\":\"Reise\",\"url_name\":\"reise\"},\"merchant\":{\"name\":\"HUKD.MyDealz.de\",\"url_name\":\"hukd-mydealz-de\",\"merchant_id\":1,\"image\":\"\"},\"tags\":null,\"thread_id\":99359,\"visit_link\":\"http:\\/\\/hukd.mydealz.de\\/visit?m=1&q=99359&API=true\",\"hot_time\":\"13 minutes ago\",\"comment_count\":5,\"availability\":\"Online\",\"can_vote\":\"yes\"},{\"title\":\"Blu-Ray - Predators: Trilogy Set (6 Discs) f\\u00c3\\u00bcr \\u00e2\\u0082\\u00ac15,52 [@Zavvi.com]\",\"deal_link\":\"http:\\/\\/hukd.mydealz.de\\/deals\\/blu-ray-predators-trilogy-set-6-discs-15-52-zavvi-com\\/99360\",\"mobile_deal_link\":\"http:\\/\\/hukdm.mydealz.de\\/deals\\/blu-ray-predators-trilogy-set-6-discs-15-52-zavvi-com\\/99360\",\"deal_image\":\"http:\\/\\/hukd.mydealz.de\\/images\\/threads\\/99360_1.jpg\",\"deal_image_highres\":\"http:\\/\\/hukd.mydealz.de\\/images\\/threads\\/high-res\\/99360_1.jpg\",\"description\":\"Bei Zavvi.com bekommt Ihr momentan die 6-Disc Blu-Ray Box von \\\"Predators\\\" f\\u00c3\\u00bcr (umgerechnet) \\u00e2\\u0082\\u00ac15,52 (inkl. Versandkosten).\\r\\n\\r\\n(Umrechnung \\u00c2\\u00a312.44 \\/ 0.8015 = \\u00e2\\u0082\\u00ac15,520) \\r\\n\\r\\nBITTE BEACHTEN: \\r\\n- Bezahlung kann mit Kreditkarte oder Paypal erfolgen. \\r\\n- W\\u00c3\\u00a4hrung sollte auf Pfund stehen (L\\u00c3\\u00a4nderflagge oben rechts). \\r\\n- Zollgeb\\u00c3\\u00bchren fallen NICHT an, der Betrag liegt innerhalb des Freibetrages (\\u00e2\\u0082\\u00ac26,30).\\r\\n\\r\\nDeutsche Tonspur ist nur bei Teil 2 vorhanden!\\r\\n\\r\\nIMDB: 7,8\\/10 (1)\\r\\nIMDB: 6,1\\/10 (2)\\r\\nIMDB: 6,5\\/10 (3)\\r\\n\\r\\nGesamtlaufzeit: 316 Minuten\",\"submit_time\":\"2 hours, 23 minutes ago\",\"hot_date\":false,\"poster_name\":\"michael8\",\"temperature\":45.3400001526,\"price\":15.52,\"timestamp\":1341323529,\"expired\":\"false\",\"forum\":{\"name\":\"Deals\",\"url_name\":\"deals\"},\"category\":{\"name\":\"Entertainment\",\"url_name\":\"entertainment\"},\"merchant\":{\"name\":\"HUKD.MyDealz.de\",\"url_name\":\"hukd-mydealz-de\",\"merchant_id\":1,\"image\":\"\"},\"tags\":null,\"thread_id\":99360,\"visit_link\":\"http:\\/\\/hukd.mydealz.de\\/visit?m=1&q=99360&API=true\",\"hot_time\":\"37 minutes ago\",\"comment_count\":4,\"availability\":\"Online\",\"can_vote\":\"yes\"},{\"title\":\"Bahn: Von Deutschland nach Luxemburg f\\u00c3\\u00bcr 35\\u00e2\\u0082\\u00ac (Berlin \\u00e2\\u0080\\u0093 K\\u00c3\\u00b6ln f\\u00c3\\u00bcr 35\\u00e2\\u0082\\u00ac auch m\\u00c3\\u00b6glich)\",\"deal_link\":\"http:\\/\\/hukd.mydealz.de\\/deals\\/bahn-von-deutschland-nach-luxemburg-35-berlin-k\\u00c3\\u00b6ln-35-auch-m\\u00c3\\u00b6glich\\/99371\",\"mobile_deal_link\":\"http:\\/\\/hukdm.mydealz.de\\/deals\\/bahn-von-deutschland-nach-luxemburg-35-berlin-k\\u00c3\\u00b6ln-35-auch-m\\u00c3\\u00b6glich\\/99371\",\"deal_image\":\"http:\\/\\/hukd.mydealz.de\\/images\\/threads\\/99371_1.jpg\",\"deal_image_highres\":\"http:\\/\\/hukd.mydealz.de\\/images\\/threads\\/high-res\\/99371_1.jpg\",\"description\":\"Nachdem es das letzte Mal mit dem Ltur Bahn Spezial f\\u00c3\\u00bcr 35\\u00e2\\u0082\\u00ac nach Paris ging, geht es nun nach Luxemburg. Da der Zug aber zumeist durch K\\u00c3\\u00b6ln f\\u00c3\\u00a4hrt, kann man so auch einfach in K\\u00c3\\u00b6ln aussteigen bzw. zusteigen und Berlin-K\\u00c3\\u00b6ln f\\u00c3\\u00bcr 35\\u00e2\\u0082\\u00ac fahren. Das Ganze funktioniert von vielen deutschen Bahnh\\u00c3\\u00b6fen, wie zum Beispiel M\\u00c3\\u00bcnchen und Hamburg. Buchbar sind diese g\\u00c3\\u00bcnstigen Zugfahrten ab jetzt bis zum 15. Juli. Hier geht es zu der offiziellen Luxemburg Webseite mit vielen Informationen zur Stadt: http:\\/\\/www.lcto.lu\\/de\\/index\",\"submit_time\":\"1 hour, 8 minutes ago\",\"hot_date\":false,\"poster_name\":\"Urlaubspiraten\",\"temperature\":62.9399986267,\"price\":35,\"timestamp\":1341328048,\"expired\":\"false\",\"forum\":{\"name\":\"Deals\",\"url_name\":\"deals\"},\"category\":{\"name\":\"Reise\",\"url_name\":\"reise\"},\"merchant\":{\"name\":\"HUKD.MyDealz.de\",\"url_name\":\"hukd-mydealz-de\",\"merchant_id\":1,\"image\":\"\"},\"tags\":null,\"thread_id\":99371,\"visit_link\":\"http:\\/\\/hukd.mydealz.de\\/visit?m=1&q=99371&API=true\",\"hot_time\":\"40 minutes ago\",\"comment_count\":2,\"availability\":\"Online\",\"can_vote\":\"yes\"},{\"title\":\"Ab dem 05.07. H\\u00c3\\u00a4agen Dazs Eiscreme, 500ml f\\u00c3\\u00bcr 3,69 in der Metro\",\"deal_link\":\"http:\\/\\/hukd.mydealz.de\\/deals\\/dem-05-07-h\\u00c3\\u00a4agen-dazs-eiscreme-500ml-3-69-in-metro\\/99032\",\"mobile_deal_link\":\"http:\\/\\/hukdm.mydealz.de\\/deals\\/dem-05-07-h\\u00c3\\u00a4agen-dazs-eiscreme-500ml-3-69-in-metro\\/99032\",\"deal_image\":\"http:\\/\\/hukd.mydealz.de\\/images\\/threads\\/99032_1.jpg\",\"deal_image_highres\":\"http:\\/\\/hukd.mydealz.de\\/images\\/threads\\/high-res\\/99032_1.jpg\",\"description\":\"Es gibt zwar kein best\\u00c3\\u00a4ndiges Sommerwetter momentan, aber lecker Eis geht immer. :)\",\"submit_time\":\"1 day, 8 hours ago\",\"hot_date\":false,\"poster_name\":\"learned\",\"temperature\":50.4300003052,\"price\":3.69,\"timestamp\":1341213712,\"expired\":\"false\",\"forum\":{\"name\":\"Deals\",\"url_name\":\"deals\"},\"category\":{\"name\":\"Food\",\"url_name\":\"food\"},\"merchant\":{\"name\":\"HUKD.MyDealz.de\",\"url_name\":\"hukd-mydealz-de\",\"merchant_id\":1,\"image\":\"\"},\"tags\":null,\"thread_id\":99032,\"visit_link\":\"http:\\/\\/hukd.mydealz.de\\/visit?m=1&q=99032&API=true\",\"hot_time\":\"41 minutes ago\",\"comment_count\":7,\"availability\":\"Offline\",\"can_vote\":\"yes\"},{\"title\":\"Zumba-Tanzkurs (5 x 60 Min.) f\\u00c3\\u00bcr 20 \\u00e2\\u0082\\u00ac statt 50 \\u00e2\\u0082\\u00ac \",\"deal_link\":\"http:\\/\\/hukd.mydealz.de\\/deals\\/zumba-tanzkurs-5-x-60-min-20-statt-50\\/99342\",\"mobile_deal_link\":\"http:\\/\\/hukdm.mydealz.de\\/deals\\/zumba-tanzkurs-5-x-60-min-20-statt-50\\/99342\",\"deal_image\":\"http:\\/\\/hukd.mydealz.de\\/images\\/threads\\/99342_1.jpg\",\"deal_image_highres\":\"http:\\/\\/hukd.mydealz.de\\/images\\/threads\\/high-res\\/99342_1.jpg\",\"description\":\"Zumba Deal bei www.cupoco.com, gilt f\\u00c3\\u00bcr Tanzschule Son Latino in Karlsruhe.\\r\\n\\r\\nKonditionen\\r\\n\\r\\nAngebot gilt nur f\\u00c3\\u00bcr Neukunden\\r\\nTerminvereinbarung unter 0721 \\u00e2\\u0080\\u0093 663 8886 oder per E-Mail an info@sonlatino.de erforderlich\\r\\nPro Person ist 1 Gutschein einl\\u00c3\\u00b6sbar\\r\\nTermine unter www.sonlatino.de\\r\\n\\r\\n---\\r\\nG\\u00c3\\u00bcltigkeitszeitraum\\r\\n\\r\\nDer Gutschein ist ab Kaufdatum f\\u00c3\\u00bcr 1 Jahr g\\u00c3\\u00bcltig.\",\"submit_time\":\"3 hours, 59 minutes ago\",\"hot_date\":false,\"poster_name\":\"good_n8\",\"temperature\":33.9900016785,\"price\":20,\"timestamp\":1341317769,\"expired\":\"false\",\"forum\":{\"name\":\"Deals\",\"url_name\":\"deals\"},\"category\":{\"name\":\"Entertainment\",\"url_name\":\"entertainment\"},\"merchant\":{\"name\":\"HUKD.MyDealz.de\",\"url_name\":\"hukd-mydealz-de\",\"merchant_id\":1,\"image\":\"\"},\"tags\":null,\"thread_id\":99342,\"visit_link\":\"http:\\/\\/hukd.mydealz.de\\/visit?m=1&q=99342&API=true\",\"hot_time\":\"59 minutes ago\",\"comment_count\":7,\"availability\":\"Offline\",\"can_vote\":\"yes\"},{\"title\":\"offline @ metro H\\u00c3\\u00a4agen Dazs Eis ab 05.07.2012\",\"deal_link\":\"http:\\/\\/hukd.mydealz.de\\/deals\\/offline-metro-h\\u00c3\\u00a4agen-dazs-eis-05-07-2012\\/99369\",\"mobile_deal_link\":\"http:\\/\\/hukdm.mydealz.de\\/deals\\/offline-metro-h\\u00c3\\u00a4agen-dazs-eis-05-07-2012\\/99369\",\"deal_image\":\"http:\\/\\/hukd.mydealz.de\\/images\\/threads\\/99369_1.jpg\",\"deal_image_highres\":\"http:\\/\\/hukd.mydealz.de\\/images\\/threads\\/high-res\\/99369_1.jpg\",\"description\":\"Ab 05.07.2012 Bei Metro....\",\"submit_time\":\"1 hour, 42 minutes ago\",\"hot_date\":false,\"poster_name\":\"viktorw\",\"temperature\":78.2600021362,\"price\":3.69,\"timestamp\":1341326008,\"expired\":\"false\",\"forum\":{\"name\":\"Deals\",\"url_name\":\"deals\"},\"category\":{\"name\":\"Food\",\"url_name\":\"food\"},\"merchant\":{\"name\":\"HUKD.MyDealz.de\",\"url_name\":\"hukd-mydealz-de\",\"merchant_id\":1,\"image\":\"\"},\"tags\":null,\"thread_id\":99369,\"visit_link\":\"http:\\/\\/hukd.mydealz.de\\/visit?m=1&q=99369&API=true\",\"hot_time\":\"1 hour, 22 minutes ago\",\"comment_count\":5,\"availability\":\"Online\",\"can_vote\":\"yes\"},{\"title\":\"Ringspun\\u00e2\\u0084\\u00a2 - Herren Canvas Plimsolls Schuhe (Black,Grey,Navy,White) f\\u00c3\\u00bcr \\u00e2\\u0082\\u00ac13,69 [@Sendit.com]\",\"deal_link\":\"http:\\/\\/hukd.mydealz.de\\/deals\\/ringspun-herren-canvas-plimsolls-schuhe-black-grey-navy-white-13-69-sendit-com\\/99365\",\"mobile_deal_link\":\"http:\\/\\/hukdm.mydealz.de\\/deals\\/ringspun-herren-canvas-plimsolls-schuhe-black-grey-navy-white-13-69-sendit-com\\/99365\",\"deal_image\":\"http:\\/\\/hukd.mydealz.de\\/images\\/threads\\/99365_1.jpg\",\"deal_image_highres\":\"http:\\/\\/hukd.mydealz.de\\/images\\/threads\\/high-res\\/99365_1.jpg\",\"description\":\"Perfekte Treter f\\u00c3\\u00bcr Freizeit, Strand, Urlaub...\\r\\nBei Sendit.com bekommt Ihr momentan sehr g\\u00c3\\u00bcnstige Herren Canvas Schuhe (in 4 verschiedenen Farben) von Ringspun\\u00e2\\u0084\\u00a2 f\\u00c3\\u00bcr (umgerechnet) \\u00e2\\u0082\\u00ac13,69 (inkl.Versandkosten nach Deutschland). \\r\\n\\r\\n(Umrechnung \\u00c2\\u00a310.97 \\/ 0.8015 = \\u00e2\\u0082\\u00ac13,686) \\r\\n\\r\\nBITTE BEACHTEN: \\r\\n- Bezahlung kann mit Kreditkarte oder Paypal erfolgen. \\r\\n- W\\u00c3\\u00a4hrung sollte auf Pfund stehen (L\\u00c3\\u00a4nderflagge oben rechts). \\r\\n- Zollgeb\\u00c3\\u00bchren fallen NICHT an, der Betrag liegt innerhalb des Freibetrages (\\u00e2\\u0082\\u00ac26,30). \\r\\n- Bei Massenbestellungen kann es zu Stornos kommen! \\r\\n\\r\\nMomentan (16:00 Uhr) sind noch folgende Gr\\u00c3\\u00b6\\u00c3\\u009fen (UK\\/EU) vorhanden:\\r\\nBlack - 7 (40.5), 8 (42), 9 (43), 10 (44.5)\\r\\nGrey - 7 (40.5), 8 (42), 9 (43), 10 (44.5), 11 (46)\\r\\nNavy - 7 (40.5), 8 (42), 9 (43), 10 (44.5)\\r\\nWhite - 7 (40.5), 8 (42), 9 (43), 10 (44.5), 11 (46)\\r\\n\\r\\nBeschreibung \\\"Ringspun Men's Plimsolls\\\":\\r\\nThe perfect shoes for just throwing on before your fun filled outing, these men's plimsolls from Ringspun are designed for both style and comfort.\\r\\n- Lace up\\r\\n- Rubber sole\\r\\n- Contrast bordering\\r\\n- Ringspun logo\\r\\n\\r\\nWeitere Infos zu Ringspun\\u00e2\\u0084\\u00a2 findet Ihr unter:\\r\\nhttp:\\/\\/ringspun.co.uk\\/\",\"submit_time\":\"1 hour, 55 minutes ago\",\"hot_date\":false,\"poster_name\":\"michael8\",\"temperature\":69.4599990845,\"price\":13.69,\"timestamp\":1341325236,\"expired\":\"false\",\"forum\":{\"name\":\"Deals\",\"url_name\":\"deals\"},\"category\":{\"name\":\"Fashion\",\"url_name\":\"fashion\"},\"merchant\":{\"name\":\"HUKD.MyDealz.de\",\"url_name\":\"hukd-mydealz-de\",\"merchant_id\":1,\"image\":\"\"},\"tags\":null,\"thread_id\":99365,\"visit_link\":\"http:\\/\\/hukd.mydealz.de\\/visit?m=1&q=99365&API=true\",\"hot_time\":\"1 hour, 22 minutes ago\",\"comment_count\":12,\"availability\":\"Online\",\"can_vote\":\"yes\"},{\"title\":\"Adidas Franz Beckenbauer  (allround) (Gr\\u00c3\\u00b6\\u00c3\\u009fe UK 6 \\/ 8) \",\"deal_link\":\"http:\\/\\/hukd.mydealz.de\\/deals\\/adidas-franz-beckenbauer-allround-gr\\u00c3\\u00b6\\u00c3\\u009fe-uk-6-8\\/99348\",\"mobile_deal_link\":\"http:\\/\\/hukdm.mydealz.de\\/deals\\/adidas-franz-beckenbauer-allround-gr\\u00c3\\u00b6\\u00c3\\u009fe-uk-6-8\\/99348\",\"deal_image\":\"http:\\/\\/hukd.mydealz.de\\/images\\/threads\\/99348_1.jpg\",\"deal_image_highres\":\"http:\\/\\/hukd.mydealz.de\\/images\\/threads\\/high-res\\/99348_1.jpg\",\"description\":\"Habe gerade beim st\\u00c3\\u00b6bern ein paar Schuhe gefunden welche recht g\\u00c3\\u00bcnstig zu sein scheinen. \\r\\n\\r\\nEs handelt sich um das Model \\\"adidas Frank Beckenbauer Allround\\\". Es kommen zu den 22 Pfund leider noch 7,99 Pfund Versand dazu so das der Endpreis ein wenig leidet. Es gibt noch eine Menge Flip Flops, Airwalk und Nike Schuhe im Ausverkauf so das mit 2 Paaren definitiv gut gesparrt werden kann. Wichtig die gr\\u00c3\\u00b6\\u00c3\\u009fen sind nat\\u00c3\\u00bcrlich stark Limitiert. \\r\\n\",\"submit_time\":\"3 hours, 25 minutes ago\",\"hot_date\":false,\"poster_name\":\"Skroggo\",\"temperature\":71.5500030518,\"price\":37.42,\"timestamp\":1341319811,\"expired\":\"false\",\"forum\":{\"name\":\"Deals\",\"url_name\":\"deals\"},\"category\":{\"name\":\"Fashion\",\"url_name\":\"fashion\"},\"merchant\":{\"name\":\"HUKD.MyDealz.de\",\"url_name\":\"hukd-mydealz-de\",\"merchant_id\":1,\"image\":\"\"},\"tags\":null,\"thread_id\":99348,\"visit_link\":\"http:\\/\\/hukd.mydealz.de\\/visit?m=1&q=99348&API=true\",\"hot_time\":\"1 hour, 27 minutes ago\",\"comment_count\":13,\"availability\":\"Online\",\"can_vote\":\"yes\"},{\"title\":\"[lokal] toom Neubiberg (Landkreis M\\u00c3\\u00bcnchen) 50% auf alles wegen Schlie\\u00c3\\u009fung\",\"deal_link\":\"http:\\/\\/hukd.mydealz.de\\/deals\\/lokal-toom-neubiberg-landkreis-m\\u00c3\\u00bcnchen-50-auf-alles-wegen-schlie\\u00c3\\u009fung\\/99358\",\"mobile_deal_link\":\"http:\\/\\/hukdm.mydealz.de\\/deals\\/lokal-toom-neubiberg-landkreis-m\\u00c3\\u00bcnchen-50-auf-alles-wegen-schlie\\u00c3\\u009fung\\/99358\",\"deal_image\":\"http:\\/\\/hukd.mydealz.de\\/images\\/threads\\/99358_1.jpg\",\"deal_image_highres\":\"http:\\/\\/hukd.mydealz.de\\/images\\/threads\\/high-res\\/99358_1.jpg\",\"description\":\"Der toom-Baumarkt Neubiberg (\\u00c3\\u0084u\\u00c3\\u009fere Hauptstra\\u00c3\\u009fe 3, 85579 Neubiberg) schlie\\u00c3\\u009ft und hat noch bis 13.07. R\\u00c3\\u00a4umungsverkauf. Ich war eben da und es ist schon sehr leer, aber das ein oder andere Schn\\u00c3\\u00a4ppchen ist zu holen.\\r\\n\\r\\nWas gibt es noch?\\r\\n- Fiskars Schneeschaufeln + Schneer\\u00c3\\u00a4umer\\r\\n- Streusalz\\r\\n- Spax-Schrauben\\r\\n- Laminat\\r\\n- Farben und Lacke (auch H\\u00c3\\u00a4mmerite)\\r\\n- Lampen + Zubeh\\u00c3\\u00b6r\\r\\n- Gartenwerkzeuge\\r\\n- Blument\\u00c3\\u00b6pfe\\r\\n- einige Gartenm\\u00c3\\u00b6bel\\r\\n- einige Klimager\\u00c3\\u00a4te\\r\\n- einige Grills (keine Weber, aber Landmann Gasgrill)\\r\\n\\r\\nWas gibt es NICHT mehr?\\r\\n- jegliche Elektrowerkzeuge au\\u00c3\\u009fer Einzelst\\u00c3\\u00bccke\\r\\n- Vorh\\u00c3\\u00a4ngeschl\\u00c3\\u00b6sser\\r\\n- Blumend\\u00c3\\u00bcnger\\r\\n\\r\\nAusgenommen sind:\\r\\naktuelle Werbeartikel, Zigaretten, Getr\\u00c3\\u00a4nke, S\\u00c3\\u00bc\\u00c3\\u009fwaren, Pfand, Dienst- \\/ Serviceleistungen, Gutscheine usw.\",\"submit_time\":\"2 hours, 38 minutes ago\",\"hot_date\":false,\"poster_name\":\"DanBurg\",\"temperature\":72.1500015259,\"price\":0,\"timestamp\":1341322660,\"expired\":\"false\",\"forum\":{\"name\":\"Deals\",\"url_name\":\"deals\"},\"category\":{\"name\":\"Anderes\",\"url_name\":\"anderes\"},\"merchant\":{\"name\":\"HUKD.MyDealz.de\",\"url_name\":\"hukd-mydealz-de\",\"merchant_id\":1,\"image\":\"\"},\"tags\":null,\"thread_id\":99358,\"visit_link\":\"http:\\/\\/hukd.mydealz.de\\/visit?m=1&q=99358&API=true\",\"hot_time\":\"1 hour, 39 minutes ago\",\"comment_count\":1,\"availability\":\"Offline\",\"can_vote\":\"yes\"},{\"title\":\"50% Gutschein f\\u00c3\\u00bcr hundeland.de und katzenland.de bei limango\",\"deal_link\":\"http:\\/\\/hukd.mydealz.de\\/gutscheine\\/50-gutschein-hundeland-de-und-katzenland-de-bei-limango\\/99289\",\"mobile_deal_link\":\"http:\\/\\/hukdm.mydealz.de\\/gutscheine\\/50-gutschein-hundeland-de-und-katzenland-de-bei-limango\\/99289\",\"deal_image\":\"\",\"deal_image_highres\":\"\",\"description\":\"W\\u00c3\\u00a4hle zwischen zwei Varianten: \\r\\nWertgutschein f\\u00c3\\u00bcr Katzenland.de: Warengutschein f\\u00c3\\u00bcr Katzenland.de, anwendbar auf das gesamte Sortiment (au\\u00c3\\u009fer Katzenstreu).\\r\\nWertgutschein f\\u00c3\\u00bcr Hundeland.de: Warengutschein f\\u00c3\\u00bcr Hundeland.de, anwendbar auf das gesamte Sortiment.\\r\\n\\r\\nKonditionen\\r\\nDer Gutschein im Wert von 30\\u00e2\\u0082\\u00ac ist auf das Vollsortiment von katzenland.de (au\\u00c3\\u009fer Katzenstreu) oder auf das Vollsortiment von hundeland.de einl\\u00c3\\u00b6sbar.\\r\\n\\r\\nDer Gutschein ist bis zum 06.09.2012 g\\u00c3\\u00bcltig und nicht mit anderen Rabattaktionen des Anbieters kombinierbar.<br \\/><b>Rabatt:<\\/b> 50%\",\"submit_time\":\"7 hours, 12 minutes ago\",\"hot_date\":false,\"poster_name\":\"Adrenalina\",\"temperature\":55.4700012207,\"price\":0,\"timestamp\":1341306193,\"expired\":\"false\",\"forum\":{\"name\":\"Gutscheine\",\"url_name\":\"gutscheine\"},\"category\":{\"name\":\"Haushalt\",\"url_name\":\"haushalt\"},\"merchant\":{\"name\":\"HUKD.MyDealz.de\",\"url_name\":\"hukd-mydealz-de\",\"merchant_id\":1,\"image\":\"\"},\"tags\":null,\"thread_id\":99289,\"visit_link\":\"http:\\/\\/hukd.mydealz.de\\/visit?m=1&q=99289&API=true\",\"hot_time\":\"1 hour, 46 minutes ago\",\"comment_count\":9,\"availability\":\"Online\",\"can_vote\":\"yes\"}],\"thread_count\":1000}}"
```

Can someone please tell me how can I display this correctly on the app?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442243/draw-string-with-normalized-scientific-notation-superscripted

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON.NET from http://Json.Codeplex.Com - it works with Unicode like a charm.

For class generation from your response you can use http://json2csharp.com/

Then just use following code:

```
 var responseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourResponseType>(responseAsString);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it didn't make any changes, it's like I have to convert the response to make the german characters appear. I don't know if "string" can handle those characters but I'm pretty sure there's a way to do it.

Comment: Hmm, let me try your example.

Comment: http://habrastorage.org/storage2/26a/331/71a/26a33171a646a610cce0da9a33e207e9.png

That's what I have from LinqPad and Json.net. Seems that unicode is parsed, but you should try on shorter string and see if it's actually being sent correctly