# Replacing/removing the metric notations like thousands "k" abbreviation

Tags: highcharts

My areaspline chart has Y axis values up to approximately 6000. Highcharts automatically changes the "000" part on my Y axis for a "k".

As I'm french and the site is meant to be in that same language, this "k" abbreviation won't make sense in my case and I'd like to have a casual "000" display instead of it.

Is this possible? How?

Comment: The "k" abbreviation _does_ make sense in French, as it is part of the [préfixes du système international d'unités](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A9fixes_du_syst%C3%A8me_international_d%27unit%C3%A9s), which, by the way, was first implemented in France.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can do this by explicitly overriding the **[`lang.numericSymbols*`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#lang.numericSymbols)** with `null` in the `defaultOptions` as follows

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {
        numericSymbols: null //otherwise by default ['k', 'M', 'G', 'T', 'P', 'E']
    }
});
```

The documentation reads as follows

> **numericSymbols: `Array<String>`**
>
> [Metric prefixes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix) used to shorten high numbers in axis labels.
>   Replacing any of the positions with null causes the full number to be
>   written. Setting numbericSymbols to null disables shortening
>   altogether. Defaults to ['k', 'M', 'G', 'T', 'P', 'E'].

**officially available from v1.2.0 (2012-08-24)
This won't work before v1.2.0 as the suffixes were hard coded then.*

### **Alternate solution**

(Should work on all versions that support formatter)

Use **[`yAxis.labels.formatter`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.labels.formatter)** and return the value as it is

```
yAxis: {
    labels: {
        formatter: function () {
            return this.value;
        }
    }
}
```

**[Disabling metric notation on axis values | Highchart & Highstock (v1.2+) @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/6EAAN/)**
**[Disabling metric notation on axis values | Highchart & Highstock (old versions) @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/hm4Bh/)**

Comment: This is a good explanation.But is there any means to represent the Y axis data in Indian number format?

Comment: Thank you, it's exactly what I wanted to do. Thanks also for editing my question, I see now it was not as clear as I thought.

Comment: @Gopinagh, yes you can of course write your own formatter. Add http://syedabdulbaqi.wordpress.com/2009/03/10/javascript-function-for-converting-string-into-indian-currency-format/ to the existing fiddle and you get http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/hm4Bh/1/ If you are talking about Lakhs, Crores, etc. then that can be done too in a similar way

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of @Jugal-Thakkar, I implemented:

```
numericSymbols: [' × 10³', ' × 10⁶', ' × 10⁹', ' × 10¹²', ' × 10¹⁵', ' × 10¹⁸'],
```

The superscripts 0 and 4-9 are UTF-8 characters only. You need to specify a font that supports these, as otherwise you will have font-substitution issues, as described in [Why the display of Unicode characters for superscripted digits are not at the same height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663251/why-the-display-of-unicode-characters-for-superscripted-digits-are-not-at-the-sa).

I use:

```
font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode, Arial Unicode MS, Cambria, Calibri, Consolas;
```

Also, I would rather have 1.8 × 10¹⁴ than 180 × 10¹², but is better than 180000000000000, which is hard to read.