# How to set highchart global options IN R

Tags: r, highcharts, rcharts, r-highcharter

I see a lot of examples in javascript but I cannot find an example to do it in R

Here is the api link: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#global

I am trying to set "timezoneOffset" and I have tried many different ways. 
When I do this in R: `highChart$global(timezoneOffset=-300)`
I do not get any warning or error, but it's not working.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Here is a piece of code:

```
library(rCharts)


highChart <- Highcharts$new()
highChart$global(timezoneOffset=-300)
highChart$chart(zoomType = "xy")
highChart$exporting(enabled = T)
highChart$xAxis(type="datetime",list( title = list(text = "Time")))
highChart$yAxis(list
                (
                  list(title = list(text = "Variance"))
                ))


highChart$series(data=list(c(x=1407795845000,y=1),c(x=1407795846000,y=2),c(x=1407795847000,y=3)))

highChart
```

As you can see, the timezoneOffset is not working when I run this piece of code and the time is still displayed in GMT.

Comment: Are you using an R package that you are not naming?

Comment: @BondedDust I am using rCharts package

Answer (score 3):

As of version 0.5.0 of `highcharter`, it seems the option `highcharter.options` is not there any more, but there are several separate options, e.g. `highcharter.lang`, `highcharter.global`, etc. So the following approach works:

```
lang <- getOption("highcharter.lang")
lang$decimalPoint <- ","
lang$numericSymbols <- highcharter::JS("null") # optional: remove the SI prefixes
options(highcharter.lang = lang)
```

In addition to changing the decimal point, the SI prefixes ("k", "M", "G", etc.) are turned off by setting the numericSymbols to null, see [Replacing/removing the metric notations like thousands "k" abbreviation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378181/replacing-removing-the-metric-notations-like-thousands-k-abbreviation).

Answer (score 2):

The highcharter options can be accessed, but they are set inside the standard R options under the list element `highcharter.options`. They are not given directly to the highchart, and inside `highchart()`, there is the code line `opts <- getOption("highcharter.options", list())`.

I don't think there is another way than just get the options, alter whatever options you need to change and then set the options again with your additions.

The following is a simple illustration:

```
library(highcharter)

# normal highchart
highchart() %>%
  hc_add_serie_labels_values(1:901, seq(1, 10, 0.01))

opts <- getOption("highcharter.options")
opts$lang$decimalPoint <- "."
options(highcharter.options = opts)

# now with "," instead of "." (confirm in tooltip)
highchart() %>%
  hc_add_serie_labels_values(1:901, seq(1, 10, 0.01))
```

Of course in your case, you need to set the `$global$timezoneOffset` part.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to switch of the `useUTC` flag to `FALSE`. Than you can set the `timezoneOffset` as you wish and save the options back.

```
global <- getOption("highcharter.global")
global$useUTC <- FALSE
global$timezoneOffset <- -300
options(highcharter.global = global)
```

For better understanding make sure you take a look at global:

```
str(global)
```