# How do you represent fractions as a string in Python?

Tags: python, string, fractions

My company just got acquired by a European company, and they represent fractions as

`"7 ¼"`

in their API response instead of the usual

`"7 1/4"`

How do I create the first format in strings? I copied the fraction from their API response but I need to map things like `7 3/4` into this weird format as well.

Comment: Have you looked into the Unicode behind the fraction’s representation? A quick internet search returns several sites [like this one](https://www.alt-codes.net/fraction-symbols).  It’s not a ‘weird’ format, it’s just farther down the code table.

Comment: [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55033436/6340496) may provide some additional insight.  Just translate for Python.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out; on Mac, you can go to TextEdit and then hit ctrl + cmd + space to bring up the Emoji window, then search for "Fraction" and find it there.